# Boundaries intercommunication restrictions Java EE

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, boundary

Applying the [Boundary-Control-Entity](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/core.tech.common.extend_supp/guidances/guidelines/entity_control_boundary_pattern_C4047897.html) (BCE) pattern in Java EE:

```
@Stateless //1st boundary
public class A {}

@Stateless //2nd boundary
public class B {}
```

Until now, all it's ok, now, let's supose that for some reason I need use some services exposed by B on A. So, A now looks like:

```
@Stateless 
public class A {
    @Inject
    B b;
    //... call some B's methods
}
```

But, according to the BCE pattern stands for

> Control elements can communicate with each of the other two kinds, but
>   entities and boundary elements should not communicate directly.

Obviously for JPA Entities they need to communicate each other (otherwise, "JOINs" won't be possible). Then, I end with some questions related:

1) **Why communication between boundaries is forbidden?**

2) Under Java EE, we can use @Remote interfaces, **Will this still violates the statement?**:

```
@Stateless 
public class A {
    @Inject
    RemoteB b; //now uses a remote dependency
}

@Stateless
@Remote(RemoteB.class)//implements a remote interface
public class B {}
```

3) **How Java EE solves the pattern.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some boundaries needs intercommunication is a bad smell that maybe your design needs a refactor, for example, extract common behavior in a control and use it in both. In the case of using @Remote the boundaries are highly coupled not just with the Interface but also by the DTOs used (and DTOs always duplicate state). In a SOA/microservices oriented architecture if you need this intercommunication you should prefer low coupling, that means, using json/xml messages.

Java EE lets you use jax-rs to achieve low coupling

[5th AirHacks session](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/5th_airhacks_answers_for_questions)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my advice is to use architecture as a guideline on how to structure your application, but never as a law - so always adapt it to your needs and do what is sensible, easy and fits to your situation.

The idea behind the boundary is, that it serves as the only externally visible contract to your business logic behind it, which may change and whose details are hidden. And it's reasonable to keep the dependence on other boundaries as low as possible - yet controls can make use of and can be called by many boundaries as it is needed.

Adam Bien, one of the Java EE gurus, emphasizes in his workshops and talks one this pattern, as [he explains in this example](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/bureaucratic_design_with_java_ee). Another [good article is this one](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_13).

Comment: It's curious that my confusion was given by a statement of Adam Bien, please check this link > http://youtu.be/naLTswlNKgE?t=14m , he does not give the explanation, can you explain me WHY it is Not OK?

Comment: Well I'm not an expert on that pattern, but as I stated in my 2nd paragraph, you want the boundaries to be entry point to your controls, but not coupling them with other boundaries.

Comment: Well, I asked it to Adam Bien, He will solve this the 5th AirHacks session :) > https://gist.github.com/AdamBien/e1855469d4c507427ef9 , I will update this question ASAP.